# How to set top of a view to bottom of another view

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I would like to set top of a view to bottom of another view. like this:

[image]

`A` and `B` is a symbol to show what I want to do with views.

I want to `A`(image view) symbol always below of `B` (image view) symbol.

`B` view pinned in center horizontal and top of parent view.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: set vertical spacing between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Align the top of the right view to the bottom of the left view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+drag from A to b and set a vertical spacing constraint.  From that ctrl+drag menu, you can also align the centers/edges so you can have it laid out however you want it.